# How not to restart a function when it is called on python?

Tags: python, function, user-interface, variables, restart

I wrote a taximeter. Its task is to calculate the time how long the driver is waiting for the passenger and charge money for waiting. In the console, the code worked without problems. Provided information about:

1. When the order was accepted
2. When the passenger sat down
3. How many time the driver waited (in minutes)
4. How much money the passenger must pay, provided that he was absent for more than 3 minutes.
   But when I tried to make ui, I ran into a problem. Namely, the transfer of data the variable **s_t** from first function

```
 def button_1_click(self, **event_args):
    def current_milli_time():
     return round(time.time())
    s_t = current_milli_time()
    print ('s_t' ,s_t)
    s_t
    return s_t
```

to second function

```
 def button_2_click(self, **event_args):
    def current_milli_time2():
     return round(time.time())
    e_t = current_milli_time2()
    prostoy = 0
    s_t = self.button_1_click()
    vremy = e_t - s_t
    vremy_min = int (vremy / 60)
```

I used

```
return s_t
```

And then in the second function called the first

```
s_t = self.button_1_click()
```

But for some reason, along with writing data to the s_t variable, the first function is completely restarted
console output:

```
chek first function:  Thu Dec 01 13:29:04 2022
s_t first function 1669890545
chek first function:  Thu Dec 01 13:29:09 2022
s_t first function 1669890550
s_t second function 1669890550
e_t 1669890550
vremy 0
vremy_min 0
prostoy 0
man in car Thu Dec 01 13:29:09 2022
```

Comment: What do you mean by _"the first function is completely restarted"_? The function is executed from top to bottom everytime you call it, there's nothing running in the background between calls.

Comment: Sidenotes: Don't use `str` as variable name. And maybe boil your code down to a short example that encapsulates the problem you're having (right now it's pretty confusing).

Comment: thanks, fixed 'str'. And simplified the code for a better understanding of the problem

Comment: It's unclear what you expcect to happen: You're getting `time.time()` twice, almost at the same instant, so the difference `vremy` is bound to be `0` (in particular after the rounding)?

Comment: The functions `current_milli_time` and `current_milli_time2` do the same thing: why do you need functions just to do `round`, and why are there 2 functions instead of one, defined outside of the methods?